# out of memory error when loading bitmap with BitmapFactory.decodeStream()

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying to fetch bitmap from file and what I get is out of memory exception, here is the code, I have tried everything - bitmap.recycle, bitmap == null, setting largeHeap to true in Manifest - but the error still happens. The error happens at **bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);** The solution should work from jelly bean android versions till the newest one. Here is the code:

```
mMemoryStorage.mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < mMemoryStorage.AllsongsArray.size(); i++) {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(mMemoryStorage.AllsongsArray.get(i).mPath);
        mMemoryStorage.mRetriever.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        inputStream.close();

        byte[] art = mMemoryStorage.mRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (art != null) {

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(art);
            *Error//////bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);////////////Error*

            final int maxSize = 512;
            int outWidth;
            int outHeight;
            int inWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            int inHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            if (inWidth > inHeight) {
                outWidth = maxSize;
                outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
            }
            else {
                outHeight = maxSize;
                outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
            }
            //CAUSES OUT OF MEMORY ERROR
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, outWidth, outHeight, false);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
            mMemoryStorage.AllsongsArray.get(i).mBitmapEmbedded = resizedBitmap;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
mMemoryStorage.mRetriever.release();
```

Comment: Edit in  Manifest  Add <application
         android:largeHeap="true" ....> Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?rq=1

Comment: Oh, I haven't mentioned it - this doesn't work either.

Comment: @MM Don't do that.  Unless you have a really unique app, its a hack.  Fix the actual problem instead.

Comment: @KarlssonMakhno Your app in general is using too much memory.  The first question to ask is if this is a huge image.  If it is, that may be the problem (images take about 4*width*height bytes of memory).  If not, you need to take heap dumps and see where your app is using memory and either reduce it or fix any leaks.  Make sure you're using row recycling for lists and caches for images.

Comment: Ok, I will try this, thanks.

Comment: @GabeSechan BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();   options.inSampleSize = SampleSize;  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath(), options);

Comment: which sample size to choose?

Comment: SampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels.Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

Comment: But the quality will be pretty low then

Comment: choose inSampleSize that works for you

Comment: Check Android Monitor in android studio to see RAM usage of your app

Comment: @KarlssonMakhno try 2 or choose inSampleSize that works for you